# Necessity of being rigorous

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

#### Disclamer

I am no serious mathematician, just curious

## Context

I recently discovered some set theories, [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) and [IZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory#Intuitionistic_Zermelo.E2.80.93Fraenkel) in particular.

It made me realize that I've studied math a whole year without even knowing what a set really is (it was nothing more than a collection of objects with neither order nor repetition, as in the [Naive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory)).

On the one hand I can't blame my teacher because his only goal was for us to pass the entrance exam of some engineer school, and not to turn us into mathematicians,

But on the other hand, it doesn't make any sense to study groups and vector spaces, without a proper definition of what a set is.

Or does it ?

## Questions

1. Is mathematical consistency really necessary to study mathematics ? (Like having decided if yes or no the [LEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) holds)
2. Can any axiomatic system really be independant ? (As an axiomatic system is defined to be a **set** of axioms along with the derived theorems)

Comment: If you look closely, you'll notice that even after learning about ZFC you still don't know what a set is.

Comment: That's right. But I didn't learn it, just stumble upon its wikipedia page.
Furthermore there doesn't seem to be one unique definition.

Comment: What I mean (I don't know if that was clear actually) is that no existing theory says what a set *is*, they just give a collection (a set ? ;) ) of rules that tell us what we're allowed to do with them. At some level you just have to use naive mathematics, and naive sets. Even though you can formalize ZFC inside a model of ZFC that is studied inside a model of ZFC, etc. (modelception !) you have to begin with naive mathematics at some point.

Comment: We mathematicians are happy enough with what we do and we are included in the set that don't care much for studying which set we belong to.

Comment: Similarly, to study Euclidean geometry, you don't need to know what "points" and "lines" are.  They are merely arbitrary names, and they satisfy certain axioms.  If you come across some other objects (not the naive notion of points and lines) that also satisfy these axioms, then the theorems of Euclidean geometry are also true for those.

Comment: The axiom system for "group" has many different models, as is well-known.  The axiom system ZFC for sets also has many models, a fact which may not be known to non-mathematicians.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get probably a lot of responses disagreeing with me on this site, because there are a lot of people here that focus a lot on these types of logical foundations.  But in my experience, most mathematicians don't pay a lot of attention to this.  Yes, logical consistency is important, but most mathematicians take the LEM and the AoC as given. Sets can be worked with on an intuitive level without worrying about a rigorous consideration of what model you are working with.

Of course, some mathematicians do research in the implication of different models of set theory, and are really interested in what different results can be proved under different sets of axioms. Their idea of mathematics looks more like pure logic to me, which I am not really interested in, and they would probably consider me sacrilegious for my lack of interest.

Comment: That's a good point, but then how can Truth be defined in mathematics ?
(But I do understand you)

Comment: Actually mathematics is not about truth. It's about proofs. When you say "such and such theorem is true", that's actually an abuse of language ; what you mean is that you've found a proof. That this implies anything about "truth" is a leap of faith (that most mathematicians take).

Comment: @CaptainLama You can still go further down the rabbit hole even about proof: how are we so sure that what we have written is a proof when we haven't written it in any particular formal system?

Comment: @Morgan : OK ;) But I asked because I really thought that an axiomatic system to be a "place" where truth could be defined, as it was isolated from anything else and only a finite set of thing were taken into acount.